# Why when switching between cameras the speed movement value of the camera is showing for a second?

Tags: unity, c#

It's showing for a millisecond. When i switch between the cameras there is a filed that should show the current camera speed movement in case the camera is moving.

Now the cameras are not moving. But yet when i switch between the for a millisecond i see a number value on the speed filed. How can i make that if the cameras are not moving then don't display anything in the speed movement filed ?

Could be the cameras are moving a bit even if they are "not" moving ?

The switch cameras script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwitchCameras : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera[] cameras;
    public int currentCamera = 0;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (cameras == null || cameras.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No cameras assigned..", gameObject);
            this.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            // disable current
            cameras[currentCamera].enabled = false;

            // increment index and wrap after finished array
            currentCamera = (currentCamera + 1) % cameras.Length;

            // enable next
            cameras[currentCamera].enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The user information script where i update the ui Text with the cameras info:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UserInformation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text cameraName;
    public Text cameraSpeed;
    public Text cameraOriginalPosition;
    public Text nextTarget;
    public Text nextTargetPos;
    public Text nextTargetDis;
    public SwitchCameras switchcameras;
    public Transform target;

    private Vector3[] originalCamerasPosition;
    private Vector3 lastPosition;
    private Camera[] Cameras;
    private int cameraIndex = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Cameras = switchcameras.cameras;
        if (Cameras.Length > 0)
        {
            originalCamerasPosition = new Vector3[Cameras.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Cameras.Length; i++)
            {
                originalCamerasPosition[i] = Cameras[i].transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (cameraIndex == Cameras.Length)
            cameraIndex = 0;

        if (Cameras[cameraIndex].enabled == true)
        {
            cameraName.text = Cameras[cameraIndex].name;
            float camSpeed = (Cameras[cameraIndex].transform.position - lastPosition).magnitude / Time.deltaTime;
            cameraSpeed.text = camSpeed.ToString();
            lastPosition = Cameras[cameraIndex].transform.position;
            cameraOriginalPosition.text = originalCamerasPosition[cameraIndex].ToString();
            if (target != null)
            {
                nextTarget.text = target.ToString();
                nextTargetPos.text = target.transform.position.ToString();
                var distance = Vector3.Distance(Cameras[cameraIndex].transform.position, target.transform.position);
                nextTargetDis.text = distance.ToString();                
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cameraIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a UI empty GameObject and under it as children i have a Canvas > Panel and under Panel i have the buttons and texts and labels.

The Switch Cameras script is attached to another empty GameObject and under this one as children i have all the Cameras. Main Camera and two other Cameras.

Update:

This is what i tried now in the UderInformation script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UserInformation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text cameraName;
    public Text cameraSpeed;
    public Text cameraOriginalPosition;
    public Text nextTarget;
    public Text nextTargetPos;
    public Text nextTargetDis;
    public SwitchCameras switchcameras;
    public Transform target;

    private Vector3[] originalCamerasPosition;
    private Vector3[] lastPosition;
    private Camera[] Cameras;
    private int cameraIndex = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        Cameras = switchcameras.cameras;
        if (Cameras.Length >= 1)
        {
            originalCamerasPosition = new Vector3[Cameras.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Cameras.Length; i++)
            {
                originalCamerasPosition[i] = Cameras[i].transform.position;
            }

            lastPosition = new Vector3[Cameras.Length];
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (cameraIndex == Cameras.Length)
            cameraIndex = 0;

        if (Cameras[cameraIndex].enabled == true)
        {
            cameraName.text = Cameras[cameraIndex].name;
            lastPosition[cameraIndex] = switchcameras.lastCameraPosition;
            float camSpeed = (Cameras[cameraIndex].transform.position - lastPosition[cameraIndex]).magnitude / Time.deltaTime;
            cameraSpeed.text = camSpeed.ToString();
            cameraOriginalPosition.text = originalCamerasPosition[cameraIndex].ToString();
            if (target != null)
            {
                nextTarget.text = target.ToString();
                nextTargetPos.text = target.transform.position.ToString();
                var distance = Vector3.Distance(Cameras[cameraIndex].transform.position, target.transform.position);
                nextTargetDis.text = distance.ToString();                
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cameraIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

But still the camera/s speed part is not working good.
When i'm running the game the first camera is not moving but i see the speed value changing very fast. Then when i switch the cameras when it's getting to the moving camera it's showing the speed very fast running numbers so i can't track it with the eyes.

The question is why first time i see speed values when the camera is not moving?
And if the code should be this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your speed equation doesn't consider that the camera can change. Consider:

1. You update `lastPosition` with the position of the current camera.
2. You switch cameras.
3. `camSpeed` is calculated using the difference between the camera's current position and `lastPosition`.

Those are different positions, because `lastPosition` was the position of the last camera, not the current camera.

Fix it by either tracking `lastPosition` per camera, or update `lastPosition` when you switch cameras.

Comment: Right. I moved the line that update the lastPosition before the line float camSpeed. Now it's working fine.

Comment: If last position is updated before the calculation, it'll always be zero.

Comment: Then what i did is wrong. If you can show me one of the ways how to do it. I will try it meanwhile. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of just one `lastPosition`, keep an array of positions `Vector3[] lastPositions`, make it the same size as your `Cameras` array. Then when you're getting/setting last position, use `lastPositions[cameraIndex]`

Comment: I updated my question with what i did now with the UserInformation script. If you can please look at it. I still have a problem and i'm not sure the code is right yet. I used array of Vector3 for the lastPosition.

Comment: Like I said already, if you update the last position before the calculation, it won't work.